XSLT Split into separate segments based on key field value
i am trying to write XSLT mapping to create separate Instruction segment based on sub segment Instructiontext, whenever there is key word called /NEW LINE/ is present in the InstructionText segment. I have written a code but its giving error, Please help me on this..
i attached sample input and output as below. Please check.
Input:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TIM>
    <SBDH>
        <FIELD1>132</FIELD1>
    </SBDH>
    <TI>
        
        <TIC>           
            <Instruction>
                <InstructionText languageCode="EN">20</InstructionText>
            </Instruction>
            <Instruction>
                <InstructionText languageCode="EN">234</InstructionText>
            </Instruction>
            <Instruction>
                <InstructionText languageCode="EN">456 /NEW LINE/ 789 /NEW LINE/ 910/NEW LINE/</InstructionText>
            </Instruction>
            
        </TIC>
    </TI>
</TIM>

** Desired Output:**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TIM>
    <SBDH>
        <FIELD1>132</FIELD1>
    </SBDH>
    <TI>
        <TIC>
            <Instruction>
                <InstructionText languageCode="EN">20</InstructionText>
            </Instruction>
            <Instruction>
                <InstructionText languageCode="EN">234</InstructionText>
            </Instruction>
            <Instruction>
                <InstructionText languageCode="EN">456</InstructionText>
            </Instruction>
            <Instruction>
                <InstructionText languageCode="EN">789</InstructionText>
            </Instruction>
            <Instruction>
                <InstructionText languageCode="EN">910</InstructionText>
            </Instruction>
        </TIC>
    </TI>
</TIM>


** XSLT I used is below:**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
       
            <xsl:for-each select="//InstructionText">
            
                <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(string(InstructionText), '/NEW LINE/')">
                    <InstructionText>
                        <InstructionText><xsl:value-of select="."/></InstructionText>
                      
                     </InstructionText>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
      
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>   

Please assist here.

Please pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0, not all of them. And if you're getting an error, post the exact error message.

Within the outer xsl:for-each, your context node is the InstructionText element. You then tokenise the value of string(InstructionText), but an InstructionText element doesn't have a child called InstructionText.

If your processor supports XSLT 3.0, you should be able to do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="Instruction"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="InstructionText">
    <xsl:variable name="languageCode" select="@languageCode" />       
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '/NEW LINE/')[normalize-space(.)]">
        <Instruction>
            <InstructionText languageCode="{$languageCode}">
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </InstructionText>
        </Instruction>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>  

You can see it working here.

http://xsltransform.net/gVTZKDS
not ablet to get the output..  can you please assit.

That's not my code. And I don't think the site is working. Try at https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/.

i am not able to past xslt fiddle URL here, getting syntax issues for the code (< expected, error), but i am keeping correctly only

It works for me. See the link in my answer.

Thank you so much for your help , its working
